# Bash script - iterate through folders and move into folders of 1000

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I have 1.2 million files split out into folders, like so:

```
Everything
..........Folder 1
..................File 1
..................File 2
..................File 3
..................File 4
..................File 5 etc 
..........Folder 2
..................File 1
..................File 2
..................File 3
..................File 4
..................File 5 etc
```

If I `cd` into `Folder 1` I can run the following script to organize the files there into folders called `1`, `2`, `3`, etc. of 1000 files each:

```
dir="${1-.}"
x="${2-1000}"

let n=0
let sub=0
while IFS= read -r file ; do
    if [ $(bc <<< "$n % $x") -eq 0 ] ; then
            let sub+=1
            mkdir -p "$sub"
            n=0
    fi

    mv "$file" "$sub"
    let n+=1
done < <(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f)
```

However I really would like to run it once on the `Everything` folder at the top level.  From there it would consider the child folders, and do the by-1000 sorting so I could move everything out of `Folder 1`, `Folder 2`, etc. and into folders of 1000 items each called `1`, `2`, `3`, etc.

Any ideas?

**Edit:** Heres how I would like the files to end up (as per comments):

```
Everything
..........Folder1
.................file1(these filenames can be anything, they shouldnt be renamed)
.................(every file in between so file2 > file 999)
.................file1000
..........Folder2  
.................file1001
.................(every file in between so file1002 > file file1999)
.................file2000
```

Every single possible file that is in the original folder structure is grouped into folders of 1000 items under the top level.

Comment: +1 for good post, good formatting, good code!, and layout of filenames to be worked with BUT please edit your post to include a block that shows what your new file layout would look like. Good luck.

Comment: So would `Everything/Folder_1/File_1` end up as `Everything/1/File_1`, or as `Everything/Folder_1/1/File_1`, or something else?

Comment: Everything/1/file1 everything/1/file2 etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume your script is called organize.sh, and the *Everything* folder contains only directories. Try the following:

```
cd Everything
for d in *; do
    pushd $d
    bash ~/temp/organize.sh
    popd
done
```

#### Update

To answer Tom's question in the comment: you only need one copy of organize.sh. Say if you put it in ~/temp, then you can invoke as updated above.

Comment: pushd: cd into a directory, but remember where you were. popd: return to where you were before pushd. You can do something like: `cd $d`, do some work, then `cd ..` -- same thing.

Comment: Ah thanks, do i need organize.sh in each folder? - thing is this wont end up with 1 / 2  / 3 / 4 etc will it as it'll have 1 / 2 / 3 as subfolders of the folder

Answer (score -2):

```
Pseudo Algo:

1) Do ls for all your directories and store them in a file.
2) Do cd into each directory you copied into your file.
3) Sort all your files
4) Do cd ..
5) Repeat step 2-4 in a for loop.
```

Comment: You should never parse the output of ls: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs . Also, is the two extra characters of "your" instead of "ur" really too much to type?